# Google scripts code running slow when batching functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I use a cell to help trigger functions in a spreadsheet I made

ie: when cell A13 = "loading old orders" do this
It should run for around 4 mins then end
then it repeats this until the code finds "2015-11-09T22:40:56" in col C

I am finding that some of these calls are taking a lot longer now that the sheet is growing in size.

I am after some ideas to make the code more efficient

Thanks in advance

```
function getOldOrders(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var status = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
var StatusCellToWatch = status.getRange("A13");
var offset = 0;


if (StatusCellToWatch.getValue() === "Loading Old Orders") {  
 try {
     var beforedate = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1,21).getValue();
} 
catch(e) {
     var beforedate = "2999-03-22T19:28:02";
}
     //StatusCellToWatch.setValue(beforedate);
     getOrders('&before='+beforedate,offset);
     StatusCellToWatch.setValue('Loading Old Orders');


     //Set sheet status so that the dataset just updates and grabs new orders
     var data = sheet.getRange('C30000:C').getValues();
     var search = "2015-11-09T22:40:56";

     for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
         if (data[i][0] == search) {
             StatusCellToWatch.setValue('');
             FormatSummary();
         } 
     }
```

Comment: Here is the transcript

Comment: Please supply the entire script; there are at least two subroutines not included, and the code itself is not complete.